# Magnet and its orientation

Tags: magnetic-fields

Do magnets always points north pole without considerable deviation? Do magnets points to correct north pole or whether it points 23.1/2° right or left to it due to tilt of earth's axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnets tends to align to the field lines of a magnetic field. Earth possesses a magnetic field whose axis does not coincide with the rotation one but differs of about 11° (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field)), so in ideal conditions (no other local magnetic fields but only that of the Earth) magnets would point to the magnetic north pole that is defined as the intersection between the Earth surface and the magnetic axis (which differs from the geographic north pole).

Be also careful when talking about the tilt of the Earth axis. As far as I know, usually it is referred to the angular difference between the rotation axis and the orbital one (which, in the case of the Earth, is about 23°). And this has nothing to do with the orientation of the magnetic field.